# Make "pro" style terminal default when opening new tab/window 

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

Mac OS X 10.6

In Terminal preferences, the default startup window can be set to different style. But the keyboard shortcut "cmd-T" & "cmd-N" can only open the basic style terminal. How can I reassign the shortcut?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Open `Terminal`->`Preferences`, select `Settings` tab, choose `Pro` style and click `Default` button. Also open `Startup` tab and ensure that for the `On startup, open` option `New window with settings:`==`Pro`

Comment: Seriously, I just spent about 20 minutes trying to figure this out...

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: What would be more intuitive for selecting the default settings than selecting an item in the Settings list and clicking the Default button? By the way, **Shell > Use Settings as Default** makes the settings profile of the current terminal the default and updates the profile to match the current window settings (rows/columns, title, etc.). Is that intuitive enough?

Comment: @titaniumdecoy: Normally you don’t need to change **Preferences > Startup** unless you’ve previously customized it. By default, **On startup, open** chooses the default settings profile, and if you change the default, it uses the new default.

Comment: @Chris Page: Seems that startup style was not connected to default one in previous versions of OS X, now it is connected unless startup style is different when changing default style.

Comment: @tig, if the startup setting matches the default, changing the default also updates the startup setting. If they aren't using the same settings profile, then changing the default won't update the startup setting. You must have set the startup preference to something other than the default.