# How to set a keyboard shortcut to "Zoom" thunderbird window on Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, thunderbird

I assigned keyboard shortcut `Cmd-.` to "Zoom" a window for all applications, it works fine except for Mozilla Thunderbird, I guess that is because Thunderbird has a menu item **View -> Zoom -> Zoom in** (out, reset, etc.).  How to assign a keyboard shortcut to do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [specify nested menu titles](https://superuser.com/questions/177574/how-to-add-custom-keyboard-shortcut-for-a-nested-menu-item) like `>Window>Zoom` on 10.7, but it stopped working on 10.8.

You could also use an application like Moom or BetterSnapTool or assign a shortcut to an [AppleScript that clicks a zoom button](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46410/3936).

Comment: I assigned `Ctrl+Cmd+.` to `>Window>Zoom` for Thunderbird and I see it appears in the right menu item, however it does not work either in 10.7.4.  I see enough information to solve this in other way.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In System Preferences > Keyboard. Click the Keyboard Shortcuts tab. In the left hand pane, at the bottom, there is a "Application Shortcuts" item. Choose that, and you'll see a new pane on the right and a "+ / -" control. You'll need to click the "+" and choose Thunderbird as the application, and then type in the exact menu item you'll want to activate with the defined keyboard shortcut.

Here's an example I use for VLC:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed step, my question was about shortcut for nested menu item, @Lri answered that quite well.